# Docker doesn't reflect changes made from git

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

A new issue I started having today is that when I `git checkout main` outside of docker, the changes don't reflect inside docker.

When I `docker compose exec app bash` the folder structure does not change until I input `docker compose down` then `docker compose up`.

It used to update this automatically before today, I haven't made any changes to my `docker-compose.yaml` or `DockerFile` at all.

Other team members also use the setup and DockerFile and they don't seem to experience any of this.

Long shot but does anybody have an idea?

Here is my docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./docker/app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: example/app
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/example-dev
    networks:
      - example-net
```

I am using docker desktop Version 3.5.1 (3.5.1.7) on Mac

Comment: I suppose the git directory you are referring to is the current directory in which you run `docker compose` and which is binded to `/var/www/example-dev`?

Comment: What does `git status` gives when ran into the container? As opposed to outside?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic issue on mac OS

A solution is to use [docker sync](https://dev.to/kovah/cut-your-docker-for-mac-response-times-in-half-with-docker-sync-1e8j)

File system update from mac OS to docker is slow or not correctly handle.
docker-sync helps on this

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, and changing the permissions of the repository with `chmod +x <directory>` fixed the problem for me.